# SQLite.UWP.2015 Visualstudio extension Install Error

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

When trying to install the SQLite UWP Visualstudio extension from sqlite.org the installer fails with the error "the method or operation is not implemented."

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with Update 3 of Visualstudio 2015, and happens if there's an older version of the extension already installed.

In VS navigate to Tools -> Extensions and Updates...

Then search for SQLite in the "Installed" category. After removing the old version of the extension the installer for the new one will work without issue.